# How to wrap an object into a function return this object using jscodeshift

Tags: jscodeshift

Let's say I have the following file

```
export default {
  foo: 'bar'
}
```

How can I transform this file using jscodeshift so it wraps the object into function like this:

```
export default () => ({
  foo: 'bar'
})
```

My main problem is how to use the `api.jscodeshift.arrowFunctionExpression()`, especially how to create the function body. Cause I think all I need to do, is to replace the `ObjectExpression` with a function that has the `ObjectExpression` as its body.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use `j.template.expression` which is a tagged template that lets you interpolate JavaScript with existing nodes:

[Complete example](https://astexplorer.net/#/gist/bab79ba747c9113a597ee78b4ba240b0/2f321be59e41873dcb86d94bae4de41eb677af09):

```js
  return j(file.source)
    .find(j.ExportDefaultDeclaration)
    .find(j.ObjectExpression)
    .replaceWith(
      path => j.template.expression`theme => ${path.node}`
    )
    .toSource();
```

Answer (score 0):

Found out by myself. `arrowFunctionExpression` take a list params and then a `blockStatement`. This will generate the function:

```
const fn = j.arrowFunctionExpression(
    [{ type: "Identifier", name: "theme" }],
    j.blockStatement([j.returnStatement(stylesObject)])
  );
```

Then create a new `exportDefaultDeclaration` and pass the function to it.

```
const e = j.exportDefaultDeclaration(fn)

  return j(e).toSource();
```